# Firebase .data() function is not found

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I did manually set up the entire data into Firebase Firestore have been trying to retrieve the data as followed

```
import app, { db } from "./app";
import {
    addDoc,
    collection,
    doc,
    getDocs,
    getFirestore,
    limit,
    orderBy,
    query,
    setDoc,
    Timestamp,
} from "firebase/firestore";


export default async function getEvents() {
    const db = getFirestore(app);
    const first = collection(db, "Events");
    const docSnap = await getDocs(first);
    console.log(docSnap.data());
}
```

The thing over here is that the console throws an error saying that `docSnap.data()` is not a function

> TypeError: docSnap.data is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes apparently the mistake I did was that I need to specify the document before I get it's data, So the correct thing to do would be

```
console.log(docSnap.docs[0].data());
```

If you want all the data from all the elements maybe you can loop over them or just map them depending over your preference.

Comment: Make sure to select this as the solution so that people with the same issue will find it.

Comment: How did you missed the official firebase [examples](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection) for that?

Comment: @SergeySosunov The data I had was an array of multiple elements which made me mess up. The docs had a single element in them as an example, or that's how I interpreted it. I am sorry, I have a long way to go